# Visual Studio For Mac 2019 - ASP.NET MVC [Not Core] Bin/Release Only Contains DLL Files

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, macos, visual-studio, amazon-web-services

I have an ASP.NET MVC Web Application that I've been building on my Mac using Visual Studio 2019. When I rebuild the solution, the bin folder contains only DLL files - why is this and how can I fix it? I'm expecting to see my CSHTML files, etc, in here so I can deploy the website to my AWS webserver.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The `bin` folder using Visual Studio 2019 on windows also only contains the `.dll` files.  The views remain where they are, and the act of **publishing** should generate a zip file that contains everything that's needed to deploy.  Which leads to - what is your intended deployment method to AWS?  The bin folder not having the `cshtml` files is not your problem here.

Comment: Hi Brendan, for now I wanted to manually deploy my website to AWS. There is no publish option as you would normally see in Windows, so I was going to copy the release folder into my IIS website for now until I have a full deployment system in place. The release folder should usually contain more than just DLLs which is where I’m confused